# How to get a better formatted JSON Response in DjangoRestFramework UI

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an APIVIEW in DRF which I have written some views in it to get some Response, I would like to get a better formatted JSONResponse.

Views.py

```
class Pay(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/262762380"
        payload = {}
        files = {}
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)
        return Response(response)
```

This is a pictorial representation of the bad formatted JSONResponse I am getting which I would like to improve. Thanks

[image: DRF UI]

Comment: Not sure what you want  to achieve here but you are actually constructing a new requests.request object and passing that as data to the DRF Response method, which by default renders this to JSON. The result is what you would expect.

To retrurn your own payload data jou simply pass this as  Pyhton list or dict (or even scalar value) to the Response method. Much better: have a look at [Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to do the boring work for you based on your model class.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @jlapoutre, but the problem here is that I am not using any models, that is why I don't know how to go about it. I wouldn't mind if you could help me with it. Thanks

Comment: OK so the generic solution still holds: create the structure you want to return as a set of simple Python objects and return this. Will add an answer to do some code formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the case you don't have a Model but rather some data structure you get in some other way (as in a response from a third party API) just return a Response with this data structure as argument.

In this case you are effectively acting as a kind of proxy between the 3rd party API and your client, if that is what you intend (be sure not to leak private data!)

Example:

```py
class Pay(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/262762380"
        payload = {}
        files = {}
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        # no need for 'data' and 'files' arguments with method GET
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        # do some validation, at least check for response.status_code
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            return Response(data)
```

There are many more possibilities when using the [requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: AM really grateful for you answer Sir, I got perfectly the result I needed in clean JSON Response unlike the other rough one

Comment: I would be glad if you could help with this slightly related question also Sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64551404/how-to-send-request-using-a-field-in-djangorestframework-ui/64552744#64552744