# How to send request using a field in DjangoRestFramework UI

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am making a request from some external source, I am successfully able to make the request both manually by passing the "reference_no" in my url, but I will like to have a way whereby I can put the "reference_no" in the DRF UI and click on post which would send the data to the external endpoint and fetch the Response.

I don't know if this is possible but I would be glad to get a way across this.

[image: Image Description of what I want]

views.py

```
class Pay(APIView):
    def get(self, request, reference_id):
        url = f"https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/{reference_id}"
        payload = {}
        files = {}
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)
        return Response(response)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('pay/<str:reference_id>', Pay.as_view(), name='pay'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work, I would do small change: get data from response (`.json()`) to create DRF Response:

```py
class Pay(APIView):
    def get(self, request, reference_id):
        url = f"https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/{reference_id}"
        payload = {}
        files = {}
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer SECRET_KEY',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data= payload, files=files)
        return Response(data=response.json()) # create DRF Response
```

In the example above there is no error handling, please add it.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Sir, But what i would like to really achieve is the ability to input the reference_id inside a field in the DRF UI and click send and then it gets the Response for me instead of manually adding it into my views which is unprofessional